# Fourier transform of indicator function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, characteristic-functions

Given a set of complex numbers $\mathcal A$, is there a convenient solution for the Fourier transform of its indicator function $\chi_{\mathcal A}(z)$? More specifically, if $\mathcal A$ is a set of natural numbers and $A(x)$ is the number of elements of $\mathcal A$ less than or equal to $x$, can we express $\mathcal F[\chi_{\mathcal A}](\xi)$ in terms of $A(x)$ or some other metric of $\mathcal A$?

I'm a complete beginner with respect to Fourier series, so I apologize if this is something I should be able to solve by myself.

(Note: when tagging, I noticed that the characteristic-functions tag description mentions that random variables are the Fourier transform of characteristic functions, but I couldn't find anything about that online. Feeling very stupid. Explanation?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic case is that the Fourier transform of the indicator function of an interval centered at zero is a sinc function. So by this calculation and linearity, your question essentially reduces to determining how the Fourier transform is affected by translation. It is easy to calculate this by a change of variable: you find that $\widehat{f(x-x_0)}(\xi) = e^{-i x_0 \xi} \hat{f}(\xi)$. (As usual, everything is slightly different if you use a different normalization.) So the Fourier transform of a sum of indicator functions of intervals is a sum of sincs, each multiplied by $e^{-i x_k \xi}$ where $x_k$ is the center of the $k$th interval.

On characteristic functions of random variables: the characteristic function of a random variable is the Fourier transform of its density (in the sense of distribution theory, if the variable isn't continuous).

Comment: So then $\mathcal F[\chi_{\mathcal A}](\xi)=\sum_k \frac{\sin x}x e^{-x_k \xi}$ for appropriate $k$?

Comment: @Laertes Wait, I may misunderstand: is $\mathcal{A}$ a collection of intervals, or a collection of discrete points, or what? If $\mathcal{A}$ is a union of intervals $I_k$, then what I said above is $\mathcal{F}[\chi_\mathcal{A}](\xi)=\sum_k \frac{\sin(a_k x)}{b_k x} e^{-i x_k \xi}$ if $A$ is a union of intervals $I_k$. Here $a_k,b_k$ depend on the length of $I_k$ and $x_k$ is the center of $I_k$.

Comment: $\mathcal A$ is a set of complex numbers, or in the specific case natural numbers. However, using intervals might actually be easier to apply to my specific problem, so I'll take either.

Comment: If you have a discrete set, then the Fourier transform of the indicator function is just zero, since that indicator function is zero a.e.

Comment: @Laertes Also be careful: what I wrote assumed that the $I_k$ are real intervals.

Comment: Real is fine; in regard to your above comment, how exactly do $a_k$ and $b_k$ depend on the length of $I_k$? If the length of $I_k$ is the same for all $k$, can we simplify them?

Comment: @Laertes It depends on the normalization. The "basic" case is written here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function#Fourier_transform_of_the_rectangular_function By changing variables you can adapt this to your specific case. (Cf. "time scaling" in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Basic_properties) Also I had a typo, $x$ above should have been $\xi$ (but $x_k$ was correct).